# Finding an Image's Width After Adding a CSS Class via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a script setup that detects whether an image is portrait or landscape. In this case the image is landscape. What I want to do is crop and center the image using absolute positioning, setting the height to 100% and giving it a negative margin-left based on half the image's width.

I was able to do the above but here's the the problem I'm running into: The images I'm using all have variable widths/heights due to each of them being called from an API (in this case the Spotify API). That being said I had to use some Javascript to find their correct width. Its doing just that but only before I add the class `landscape`, so in actuality its dividing the image width before **being** resized to fit in the 250px x 250px `#container` div using the css from that class.

What I want it to do is divide the image's width **after** after its been resized using the properties from the `landscape` class.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/9c4880556288e2f4d098a104f5125e477611be32" >
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#container {height: 250px; width: 250px; overflow: hidden; position: relative;}

.landscape {position: absolute; height: 100%; left: 50%;}

.portrait {width: 100%;}
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    var $img       = $('img'),
        $imgHeight = $img.height(),
        $imgWidth  = $img.width();  

    if ($imgWidth > $imgHeight) {
        $img
            .addClass('landscape')
            .css({
                marginLeft: '-' + $imgWidth / 2 + 'px',
            });
    } else {
        $img.addClass('portrait');
    }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get image size (height & width) using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript)

Comment: Are you using multiple `<img>` elements per page that you want this script to run on? If so, you'll need an `each` function.

Comment: @Bram Vanroy I'm using one image as an avatar per page but will most likely be using more through an index page. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should refetch the width after you applied the class. In your example you're using a cached width from *before* you actually applied the class. Working code:

```
$(function() {
    var $img       = $('img'),
        $imgHeight = $img.height(),
        $imgWidth  = $img.width();  

    if ($imgWidth > $imgHeight) {
        $img
            .addClass('landscape')
            .css({
                marginLeft: '-' + $img.width() / 2 + 'px',
            })
    } else {
        $img.addClass('portrait');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d3u9tc0g/

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I can't believed I overlooked the fact that I was using the cached value.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the value saved in `$imgWidth`, you need to recalculate it after the class is added.

```
$img
            .addClass('landscape')
            .css({
                marginLeft: '-' + $img.width() / 2 + 'px',
            });
```